# Create Standard Data File in Mifare Desfire

Tags: android

Create File in Mifare Desfire. 
Return error response  like 0x0E DESFire card related exception has occurred.
what is the correct command to create files in mifare desfire

```
CreateStdDataFile(FileNo,Com.Set.,AccessRights,FileSize)
        [8bytes]

public void CreateFile() throws Exception {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[7];
    buffer[0] = (byte) ((0x00)); //file Number
    buffer[1] = (byte) ((0xFF)); //Comm. Sett.
    buffer[2] = (byte) (0x00); // 2 & 3 Access Rights
    buffer[3] = (byte) (0x04);
    buffer[4] = (byte) (0x00);  // 4 & 5 & 6 File Size
    buffer[5] = (byte) (0x00);
    buffer[6] = (byte) (0x0F);

    sendRequest(CREATE_FILE,buffer);
}

try
{
    reader.CreateFile();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Problem accessing Desfire tag", e);
} finally {
    try {
        isoDep.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

Comment: `0xF0000` bytes sounds like a pretty big file size. Are you sure your DESFire card can hold that much data?

Comment: yes desfire card can hold much data

Comment: My point is that the bytes specifying your requested file size seem to be reversed; since the DESFire expects the data in least significant byte first. You are asking it to create a file close to one megabyte in size.

Comment: ya as per my knowledge in single file store 52 byte in desfire. and i send request to store 15 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). (See in particular the **Illustration** section.)

The DESFire instruction requires you to pass the file size in the *least significant byte* order (little-endian), but your code uses the *most significant byte* order (big-endian).

The way you currently have it in your code (`0x00, 0x00, 0x0F`) you are not asking for a file of size `0x00000F` (15) bytes, but `0x0F0000` (983 040) bytes.

To request a file of size 15 bytes, your code should be:

```
// ...
buffer[4] = (byte)0x0F;
buffer[5] = (byte)0x00;
buffer[6] = (byte)0x00;
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply using this create file but one problem that cannot read/write created  file buffer[2] = (byte) (0x00); // 2 & 3 Access Rights
    buffer[3] = (byte) (0x04); what can change in access rights to read/write file

Comment: I try this  buffer[2] = (byte) (0xE);  buffer[3] = (byte) (0x0); // 2 & 3 Access Rights but write only cannot Read this file Authentication error when read this file

Comment: In order to really understand the instruction set for the DESFire cards, you should consult the technical specification from [NXP](http://www.nxp.com).

Comment: ok thanks for your reply i contact to nxp technical assistant